# How to remove section of a cell that is duplicate to a second cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have an excel spreadsheet with items in column B beginning with the same text as column A, for example:

cell A1 - Groceries-Food-Fruit

cell B1 - Groceries-Food-Fruit - apples, oranges, pears

How can I remove the duplicate words, (Groceries-Food-Fruit) from cell B1 using a formula?

Thanks

I've researched ways of removing duplicates, but cannot find a formula for this particular situation

Comment: You can't remove content with a formula. For that you would need VBA (or a user)

Comment: A few ways, one ìs `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,1)`. Note that you'd probably also like to delete the trailing spaces and hyphen. In such case, `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1&" - ",1)` could do, where the 3rd parameter would probably be overkill. A 2nd option could be `=MID(B1,LEN(A1)+3,LEN(B1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the cells follow the same trend you posted then this would work:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:A10,B1:B10)),MID(B1:B10,LEN(A1:A10)+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" - ",B1:B10))=TRUE,4,2),99),""),"")
```

If the entire value of cell A1 is found in the beginning of cell B2 then it trims it out. The benefit is it will work for several variations. Notice in B1 I removed the spaces around the hyphen and it still works.

[image: Example]